# Wait() method not needed for the task returned by the ContinueWith method?

Tags: c#, task

Why does the code work even if I don't use the `Wait()` method for the second task returned by method `ContinueWith`?

If I do not use the `Wait()` method for the first task, then nothing will work, but not for the second.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            void MyMethod1()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(1);
            }

            void MyMethod2(Task MyTask)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(2);
            }

            Task MyTask1 = new Task(MyMethod1);

            MyTask1.Start();
            MyTask1.Wait();

            Task MyTask2 = MyTask1.ContinueWith(MyMethod2); //Why it is work?
            //MyTask2.Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to search Google for `ContinueWith`? THe first hit for me was the documentation that clearly explains what is going on. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=net-5.0

Comment: You shouldn't be using `.Wait()` at all. So: stop doing that. Also, the Task constructor that takes a delegate is strongly advised against. Depending on what you're trying to do here: probably `Task.Run` and `await` are your friends, perhaps with a `static async Task Main()` entry-point. You shouldn't need `.ContinueWith`, either - just `await`

Comment: @Enigmativity, If I asked a question it is means I do not understand, can you write the beginning of the text from an article that explains everything?

Comment: Additional thought: nothing in the code in the question remotely benefits from involving a task. I was going to write an example using `await`, but : there's really nothing *to await* here, unless you're deliberately shifting work between threads (for example, to unblock a UI thread, which doesn't apply in the case of a console exe). I'm not trying to be dismissive here - quite the opposite. If you can clarify *why* you're using tasks here, a more reasonable and illustrative example may be possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I haven't gotten to the chapter on async await.

Comment: @NikVladi - "Creates a continuation that executes asynchronously when the target Task completes."

Comment: @Enigmativity, I haven’t gotten to the exact chapter on async await yet, so I don’t understand what asynchronously means physically. The task returned by the ContinueWith method is executed in which thread that is already created for the main task?

Comment: Why are you using tasks if you haven't got to the chapter on async/await?

Comment: @Llama, Because the Microsoft Visual C # Step by Step Ninth Edition book comes first with CHAPTER 23
Improving throughput by using tasks and only then comes the chapter CHAPTER 24
Improving response time by
performing asynchronous operations. So it's not my fault, I'm new.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a well-written book, based on the description here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because the console application is exiting before the output is written to the console by the background tasks.

If you add `Console.ReadLine()` to the end of the method and try running it without any `.Wait()` you'll see that it outputs `1` and `2` as expected.

So, why does this happen?

Well, it's because there's an overhead associated with the first write to the console - an overhead that *doesn't* occur for subsequent writes.

So when you have no `Wait()` the first `Console.WriteLine()` has not had time to finish before the program exits.

However, when you add the `Wait()` to the first task then the first `Console.WriteLine()` has (obviously) finished and the second `Console.WriteLine()` doesn't have the overhead associated with the first one, and it has time to finish before the program exits.

(This is a race condition and the actual results may vary over different runs and different environments.)

We can perform some rudimentary timings to show the difference in time taken between the first call to `Console.WriteLine()` and the second call. (Note: Normally I use Bench.Net for timings, but that wouldn't work very well for this particular case.)

```
static void Main()
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Console.WriteLine("1");
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("First Console.WriteLine() took " + sw.Elapsed);

    sw.Restart();
    Console.WriteLine("2");
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Second Console.WriteLine() took " + sw.Elapsed);
}
```

For a release build on my PC this outputs:

```
1
First Console.WriteLine() took 00:00:00.0060951
2
Second Console.WriteLine() took 00:00:00.0000624
```

As you can see, the second call is almost 100 times faster than the first call. If the program exits in somewhat less than `0.0060951` seconds, no output will be seen.

But if a `Console.WriteLine()` has previously been executed, the program will have to exit in less than `0.0000624` seconds for the output not to appear (approximately!).

You can also demonstrate this by adding a `Console.WriteLine()` to the start of the program, so that the subsequent calls avoid the overhead of the first call:

```
Console.WriteLine("Priming");

void MyMethod1()
{
    Console.WriteLine(1);
}

void MyMethod2(Task MyTask)
{
    Console.WriteLine(2);
}

Task MyTask1 = new Task(MyMethod1);
MyTask1.Start();
Task MyTask2 = MyTask1.ContinueWith(MyMethod2); //Why it is work?
```

If you do that, the output is `1` and `2` - even without the call to `MyTask1.Wait();`.

Again, note that this is a race condition, and actual results may vary. It relies on the calls to `WriteLine()` completing before the program actually exits.

Your takeaway from this should be that multithreading is tricky, and you have to do it correctly otherwise weird stuff like this will happen!

Comment: It became a little clearer for me, but remained
issues in terms of CPU resources. These are my guesses, but perhaps you can clarify. 

Option 1. If we create one task and schedule it using the Start method and nothing else - in a console application, the Main method will finish work before our task starts. Because the task must be executed in a new thread, not the calling thread, and it takes longer to allocate resources for new thread than it takes for the Main method to finish on its calling thread. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Option 2. We use option 1, but we call the Wait method from our task, which forces the calling thread to wait until our task completes in its new thread. Here I am sure that I am right.

Option 3. We use option 1, but first run Console.WriteLine ("Priming") as you wrote. Then the task will end in the same thread as work the Main method, that is, the caller because resources have already been allocated for it? This is a question, do I understand correctly?

Comment: Option 4. We use option 2, from the task, we call MyTask1.ContinueWith (MyMethod2) and we also see that everything works even without MyTask1.ContinueWith (MyMethod2).Wait(), also in a separate thread in which the task MyTask1 worked and not the calling thread of the method main just because resources have already been allocated for the work of MyTask1. Do I understand correctly?

Are things like this?

Comment: In other words, to guarantee the completion of the task that return ContinueWith(), is there a need to use Wait method?

Comment: @NikVladi No, it suffices to wait for the continuation task, because that won't start until the previous task completes.

Comment: Perhaps the translator translated my words incorrectly when I wrote the comment.
You mean that you need to do MyTask2.Wait() and then we definitely guarantee the work of MyTask1 and MyTask2.
If we do only MyTask1.Wait(), but do not do MyTask2.Wait(), then we do not guarantee the work of MyTask2. Now right?

Comment: @NikVladi That is correct.